# How to use the 'source' command to activate a virtual environment in a separate gnome-terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I am trying to activate my virtual environment using a gnome-terminal.

When I type the following code in terminal,

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'source $HOME/dir/to/virtual/environment/bin/activate; exec bash'
```

a new terminal opens, however virtual environment is not activated.

On the other hand if I use other commands (but not `source`) such as,

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'echo "that one works"; exec bash'
```

then I see that new terminal opens with message that I entered.

I see that those are different type of commands, but couldn't make `source` work.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: When you run `bash -c 'source $HOME/dir/to/virtual/environment/bin/activate; exec bash'` in an existing terminal, do you get another shell with virtual env ?

Comment: @Philippe thanks for your reply. After your comment I noticed that actually virtual environment is getting activated (even in my code above with gnome-terminal) however shell prompt is not changing to reflect the current virtual environment.